# How to open, parse and process XML file with Ox gem like with Nokogiri gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I want to open an external XML file, parse it and use the data to store in my database. I do this with Nokogiri quite easy:

```
file = '...external.xml'
xml = Nokogiri::XML(open(file))

xml.xpath('//Element').each do |element|
  # process elements and save to Database e.g.:
  @data = Model.new(:attr => element.at('foo').text)
  @data.save      
end
```

Now I want to try the (maybe faster) Ox gem (https://github.com/ohler55/ox) - but I do not get how to open and process a file from the documentary.

Any equivalent code examples for the above code would be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: I didn't know about Ox. It seems faster than Nokogiri. Is it likely that Ox will take over Nokogiri?

Comment: Probably not. Ox is very fast, but supports only a small fraction of the features Nokogiri provides. For example, if you need XPath support, proper namespace support, XSLT, etc., then Ox isn't really a valid option. Not to downplay Ox's value--it just has a more limited application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use XPath to locate nodes in Ox, but Ox does provide a `locate` method. You can use it like so:

```
xml = Ox.parse(%Q{
  <root>
    <Element>
      <foo>ex1</foo>
    </Element>
    <Element>
      <foo>ex2</foo>
    </Element>
  </root>
}.strip)

xml.locate('Element/foo/^Text').each do |t|
  @data = Model.new(:attr => t)
  @data.save      
end

# or if you need to do other stuff with the element first
xml.locate('Element').each do |elem|
  # do stuff
  @data = Model.new(:attr => elem.locate('foo/^Text').first)
  @data.save      
end
```

If your query doesn't find any matches, it will return an empty array. For a brief description of the `locate` query parameter, see the source code at [element.rb](https://github.com/ohler55/ox/blob/5e488ffb9b2f63081db788465efec48fdd4292f5/lib/ox/element.rb).

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://www.ohler.com/ox/):

> ```
> doc2 = Ox.parse(xml)
> ```

To read the contents of a file in Ruby you can use `xml = IO.read('filename.xml')` (among others). So:

```
doc = Ox.parse(IO.read(filename))
```

If your XML file is UTF-8 encoded, then alternatively:

```
doc = Ox.parse( File.open(filename,"r:UTF-8",&:read) )
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Open and parse works so far" But how do I go through the content as with "xml.xpath('//Element').each" - xpath does not work as doc.xpath...

Comment: I didn't see this as part of your original question. You're basically asking, _"How do I use Ox, like, all of it?"_ I will not answer this question, because IMHO you are now out of bounds for Stack Overflow. It does not appear that you have read the documentation, or made an attempt to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Phrogz, to be fair to @Bob, there is not much documentation, especially for the `locate` method. I could only find an explanation of the custom query language Ox uses in the `lib/ox/element.rb` file.

Comment: @kardeiz I dunno, [this documentation](http://www.ohler.com/ox/Ox/Element.html#locate-instance_method) seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @Phrogz, good point and I agree the documentation is reasonable. But that page is a good number of clicks from the Github page, and it's not obvious that `Element` is the place to look. Locating nodes is a pretty important part of parsing XML, so it would be nice if the author mentioned `locate` in the README and perhaps linked to the docs (since a custom query language is used).